# Elegant way of doing if else statement with a Flux

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-mongodb, project-reactor

I have the following kotlin method which currently uses a non-reactive mongodb repository (spring data) which returns a list.

```
  fun register(userRegistration: UserRegistration) {
    val existing = userRepository.findByTokenOrUserId(userRegistration.deviceToken, userRegistration.userId)
    var alreadyRegistered = false
    if (existing.isNotEmpty()) {
      existing.forEach {
        if (!isAlreadyRegistered(it, userRegistration)) {
          userRepository.delete(it)
        } else {
          alreadyRegistered = true
        }
      }
    }
    if (!alreadyRegistered) {
      val pnUser = PnUser(userRegistration.userId, userRegistration.deviceToken, userRegistration.region, userRegistration.locale, userRegistration.deviceType, userRegistration.osVersion, userRegistration.appVersion, userRegistration.timezone)
      userRepository.save(pnUser)
    }

  }
```

How can I have the same behavior in an elegant way if userRepository.findByTokenOrUserId would return a Flux of PnUser instead of a List?

Thanks

Comment: you might consider using kotlin coroutines which would let you write async code as you would write imperative and it supports project reactor with await extension function

Comment: @MartinTarjányi Coroutines are conceptually less powerful than reactive programming.

Comment: The most elegant way is to split the `Flux` and filter one for existing users and the other for nonexisting users. Then do whatever logic you want to do and merge them together in the end.

Answer (score 1):

As @Markus pointed out the most elegant way would be to split the `Flux` using `Flux.groupBy` and then doing the logic for each key.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55892421/the-most-efficient-way-to-split-a-flux-to-multiple-fluxes-in-reactor-3) for more information:

Comment: I would not even go for `groupBy` as it still requires to match which key you are dealing with in an ugly if-condition. I would split it by using a hot `Flux`, filtering it in two different streams for the two opposing predicates, and joining it by using`merge`.

Comment: I see, I was thinking of performing actions based on the key but I can see your point, it would be easier using two different streams honestly.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't do exactly the same but for me it will do:

```
fun registerUser(userRegistration: UserRegistration) {
userReactiveRepository.findByTokenOrUserId(userRegistration.userId, userRegistration.userId).map {
  if (!isAlreadyRegistered(it, userRegistration)) {
    userReactiveRepository.delete(it).map {
      val pnUser = PnUser(userRegistration.userId, userRegistration.deviceToken, userRegistration.region, userRegistration.locale, userRegistration.deviceType, userRegistration.osVersion, userRegistration.appVersion, userRegistration.timezone)
      userReactiveRepository.save(pnUser)
    }
  }
}
```

}