# What's the most efficient way to split a heterogeneous flux to multiple fluxes?

Tags: project-reactor, reactor

What's the most efficient way to split a heterogeneous flux to multiple fluxes by pattern matching?

We have a use case where we want to consume from multiple Kafka topics and then we want to split into multiple streams. How can we do it?

Comment: Very similar (may be a dupe): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55892421/the-most-efficient-way-to-split-a-flux-to-multiple-fluxes-in-reactor-3

Comment: Any other way other than group by? And how is the performance of group by? We are dealing with billions of data

Comment: It depends on the number of groups really - if you've got billions of *groups* then it might not be appropriate, but if you've just got a relatively low number of groups and billions of records then it should be ok. Best is to profile it and see.